# Repurposing outdoor LED security floodlights for an indoor sconce

Tags: led, motion-sensor

I am trying to create a very bright wall sconce using two LED security floodlights. I have disassembled the floodlights so I could remove them from the very bulky, heavy duty outdoor metal packaging. I wish to disable the photosensitive/motion switch. The light/motion sensor has two red wires coming out of it that lead into a circuit board. If I disconnect those two red wires from the motion/light sensor and then connect them to each other, will I bypass the photo sensor and enable the light to be turned on and off using a wall switch? Thank you. Charlie

Comment: In theory yes, but that depends on the circuit. If you let us know the model number or some pictures of the lamp in question, we could possibly give you some help! Sometimes you can remove this circuit all together if the LEDs have their own drivers. Again a picture of the inside of the lamp, including the circuit in question, would help.

Comment: Pictures , Make / Model is more helpful - you might have a BYPASS switch and that would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.  A lot of LED floods actually use a 12V motion sensor as they are half the price of a 120V sensor.  What's unclear is whether the motion sensor switches lamp current, or if it just gives a pilot signal to the circuit board.  I suppose you could try it.

However in your haste to remove bulky, heavy metal "packaging", I hope you didn't remove the essential heat sinks.  If so, you'll need to get some data sheets on your LEDs or comparables and then do some learning about how to craft heat sinks.  The efficacy of the heat sink is what's important, the LED doesn't care what it looks like... if it looks like a stylish sconce, that's fine.